# How can do I make JavaScript Synchronous while using Async/Await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, async-await, synchronization

I need to sequentially iterate through an array of URLs, awaiting asynchronous responses for each, before moving to the next URL.

I was initially expecting this to be synchronous. (I also tried `.map` in place of `.forEach`)

```
const urls = [ 'https://url.com', 'https://url.com/difPage', 'https://url.com/difPage2' ]

urls.forEach(async url => {
    const data = await performAsyncUrlFunction(url)
})
```

Comment: Just use a regular loop and still have `await` inside. No need for recursion or anything at all complex.

Comment: forEach loop I can understand, but why wont it work with  map?

Comment: @NazrulChowdhury For the same reason it doesn't work with forEach - in both cases the iteration is done in full, without waiting for async execution of the callback. If you want to do a *sequential* map, then either use a regular loop or collect the result into an array with a regular loop and `await` then map over the collected array. If you don't care about doing it sequential, map into promises and use `Promise.all()`

Comment: Ah thanks! Thought I had tried a regular for loop and it wasn't working. Just tested and it worked. Amazin'. Will update answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is a for loop. (Thank you [@VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz))

For reference, the `performAsyncUrlFunction` was using Puppeteer to extract images from the provided url and saving them.

```
const urls = [ 'https://url.com', 'https://url.com/difPage', 'https://url.com/difPage2' ]

const asyncFunc = async () => {

    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        await performAsyncUrlFunction(urls[i])
    }

}

asyncFunc()
```